# What are advantages and disadvantages of using your own pipeline for Jekyll GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-actions

I have a Jekyll page in the master branch of a repository and used to have a GitHub workflow that transforms my Jekyll markdown website into static HTML in a `static` branch:

### .github/workflows/build.yml

```
name: Build and deploy Jekyll site to the static branch

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: vendor/bundle
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gems-${{ hashFiles('**/Gemfile') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gems-
      - uses: helaili/jekyll-action@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          target_branch: "static"
```

Then I set GitHub pages to the static HTML content of the `static` branch and it worked fine. However I noticed that I don't need that at all, as I can just remove the workflow, point GitHub pages to the `master` branch and it will directly publish it from the `master` branch in Markdown form using Jekyll.

Now I don't know which of those two approaches I should use. Is one faster or more flexible then the other? What are the tradeoffs between them? Will GitHub look at my Gemfile or Gemfile.lock or use it's own predefined Jekyll version? Can I use any Gems I want to use any document processor or is there some invisible filter which only allows certain Gems? Does GitHub transform the page to HTML once and publish it to a hidden branch or does it run Jekyll as a server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you let GitHub build for you, there are a few considerations:

- Definitely less flexible: you can't pick the Jekyll version (it's 3.9.3 at the moment), and there is a finite [list of supported plugins](https://pages.github.com/versions/)
- [Some plugins](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-github-pages-and-jekyll#plugins) are enabled by default and can't be disabled; they are mostly around to enable painless conversion of linked Markdown documents without front matter
- `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are ignored, but they are useful to run the same setup locally as used for GitHub Pages (by way of using the `github-pages` gem)

When GitHub Pages builds your site for you, it runs a [workflow](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-12-16-github-pages-using-github-actions-for-builds-and-deployments-for-public-repositories/), which eventually will be customizable, containing these two actions:

- [actions/jekyll-build-pages](https://github.com/actions/jekyll-build-pages)
- [actions/deploy-pages](https://github.com/actions/deploy-pages)

But you don't have to configure anything yourself in terms of workflows.

I recommend reading the [*Setting up a GitHub Pages site with Jekyll*](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll) docs top to bottom, they have a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know this was possible. There's some github magic behind the scenes in the deployment of github-pages, my guess is that workflow lets you freely customize the jekyll build. See this document for a description of the limitation of github pages and the reasons why the author migrated to an external server https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2017/09/10/building-a-site-with-jekyll-on-nfsn/